# Copy to clipboard is not working in duckduckgo and MI Browsers

Tags: javascript

Copy to clipboard is working on Chrome, Firefox browser on both mobile and desktop.
But not working on MI browser and DuckDuckGo Browser(Mobile Browsers).

Here is my js code

```
<script>
//copy
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on("click",".copy_link", function(){
            var copyText = $(this).data('id');   
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);
        })
})
</script>
```

And here is my HTML code

```
<button class="copy_link" data-id="https://msort.ml/<?php echo $row['link']; ?>" >Copy</button>
```

I've tried other methods but I didn't get another method to copy from `.class`.

Here is my website snapshot

[image: Website]

Answer (score 0):

These browsers do not support the Asynchronous Clipboard API.

Comment: So how to do it. I have used bitly.com, copy option of bitly is woking on DuckDuckGo and MI Browser.

Comment: More details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript?rq=1